# Moq setup for interface with function argument

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I want to write an UnitTest with Moq 4.14.7. The method to be tested is as follows:

```
public IFoo Get(Guid id)
{
    Func<IFoo> getData = () => _repository.Get(id);
    if (_cache.TryGetAndSet(vaultId, getData, out var result))
    {
        return result;
    }
}
```

To briefly explain. I have a generic cache class. It checks in the cache if an entity with the passed guid exists. If this is not the case, the repository is called.

Now I have the following setup for the cache:

```
_cache.Setup
(
    x => x.TryGetAndSet
    (
        _vaultId,
        It.IsAny<Func<IFoo>>(),
        out foo
    )
)
.Returns(true);
```

The test works so far, but I do not achieve 100% coverage with it, because the func is not covered.

Is there a better way here than to work with `It.IsAny` and get 100% coverage?

Comment: That test covers 100% of the code you've shown. What does "because the func is not covered" mean? I'm guessing you need another test that returns false?

Comment: No with the ReSharper UnitTestCoverage tool only 88% coverage is achieved and the func is shown as not covered.

Comment: but isn´t the func what you want to mck? So why should it be covered at all?

Comment: Well without a copy of this tool I don't know what it' complaining about. If you add another test that returns false does it stop complaining? BTW [100% code coverage is a nonsense](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestCoverage.html)

Comment: your original `GetData`-func surely is never executed - and thus not covered - because you mock the only calling function - `TryGetAndSet`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere if I do a `_repo.Setup(x => x.Get(id)).Returns(It.IsAny<IFoo>);` before, it is still not called, because I have an `It.IsAny<Func<IFoo>>()` in the cache mock.

Comment: @Liam No unfortunately it still complains.

Comment: the delegate will never be executed, because the only function that ever would call it is mocked away. You essentially say: replace **every** call to `TryGetAndSet` by something completely different that won´t ever touch the delegate at all.

Comment: I have also tried in the cache mock instead of the `It.IsAny<>` a `() => _repository.Setup(m => m.Get(id)).Returns(foo)` but it expects an IFoo as return value, but gets the repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture the arguments passed to the member and invoke the function as desired.

```
//...

IFoo mockedFoo = Mock.Of<IFoo>();

IFoo foo = null;

_repo.Setup(_ => _.Get(It.IsAny<Guid>()).Returns(mockedFoo);

_cache
    .Setup(_ => _.TryGetAndSet(It.IsAny<Guid>(), It.IsAny<Func<IFoo>>(), out foo))
    .Returns((Guid vid, Func<IFoo> func, IFoo f) => {
        foo = func(); //<-- invoke the function and assign to out parameter.
        return true;
    });

//...

//Assertion can later verify that the repository.Get was invoked
//Assertion can later assert that foo equals mockedFoo
```

`TryGetAndSet` will return `true`, and the out argument will return the mockedFoo, lazy evaluated

Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart)